# Nil can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: ruby

Проблема заключается в том, что вылезает ошибка при попытке сделать следующее

```
   array = [1,2,3,4,5]

array.each do |x|
  mass=array[0] +array[x]
  print "#{mass}"
end
```

В консоль выводится сумма каждого элемента массива с первым, но вместе с ней и ошибка. Как быть, друзья?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Ruby нумерация массивов начинается с нуля, таким образом на последней итерации вашего цикла `x` равен `5`, и при попытке получить элемент с индексом `5` по факту достается **шестой** элемент.

Этот элемент отсутствует, и возвращается `nil`, и вот при попытке сложить `array[0]` и `nil` все ломается.

Comment: Спасибо большое, это решило проблему